# Google Authorized Error - Provided Client_Id is somehow 'invalid' - Why?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

For whatever reason I am getting "Invalid Client id" error when testing the authentication flow I set up with next-auth. Here are the steps to reproduce the error:

1. Setup credentials (Client id /client secret) via google.
2. Setup environment variables in my ".env.local" file.

error:

```
Error 400: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_id
```

/api/[next-auth].js file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers
  providers: [
    Providers.Email({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),

    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  
});
```

.env.local file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ID=MY_GOOGLE_ID
GOOGLE_SECRET=MY_GOOGLE_SECRET
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here is the answer:

This line:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ID=MY_GOOGLE_ID
GOOGLE_SECRET=MY_GOOGLE_SECRET
```

Should look like this:

```
GOOGLE_ID=MY_GOOGLE_ID
GOOGLE_SECRET=MY_GOOGLE_SECRET
```

Basically, Don't prepend the "NEXT_PUBLIC_"